# How to calculate angle between two point and rotate a uiview to pint to these two point?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making a pointed arrow in one UIView class's drawRect method with arrow length fixed.
I have to calculate the center and rotation angle of the ArrowView and then add it to my view such that the arrow appears pointing from source to destination.

the  code which iam using is

```
-(void)addArrowForChessMove:(CGPoint)source andDestination:(CGPoint)destination
{

    CGPoint centerOfArrow=CGPointMake((abs(source.x+destination.x)/2), (abs(source.y+destination.y)/2));

    DrawExperiment *drw=[[DrawExperiment alloc]initWithArrowHeight:70];
    drw.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 25, 70);
    [drw setCenter:centerOfArrow];
    [drw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [drw setTag:1002];

    float angleVal = atan2((destination.x - source.x) , (destination.y - source.y))*180/M_PI;
if ((destination.y -source.y) > 0) 
    {
        if((destination.x - source.x)<0)
        {
            angleVal= angleVal+M_PI_2;
        }
                 NSLog(@"%f====%f",(destination.y -source.y),(destination.x - source.x));


    }
    else if ((destination.y -source.y) < 0) 
    {
        if((destination.x - source.x)<0)
        {
            angleVal=angleVal+M_PI_2;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"%f====%f",(destination.y -source.y),(destination.x - source.x));
            angleVal= angleVal+M_PI;
        }

    }
    else if ((destination.x - source.x) < 0) 
    {
        if((destination.y -source.y)>=0)
        {
            angleVal= angleVal+M_PI;
        }
        else
        {
         NSLog(@"%f====%f",(destination.y -source.y),(destination.x - source.x));
        angleVal= M_PI;
        }
    }
    drw.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleVal);
    [self.view addSubview:drw];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self.view viewWithTag:1002]];




}`
```

` 
the code works fine for horizontal or vertical axis but when points are at an angle other then multiple of 90 then result is at time opposite.

what is the thing which i am missing..thanks

I have added the adjustment code as the arrow can  be in any direction it has solved many issues but there are still issues with 45 degree and 135 degree...

NOTE :- I welcome Mark down as a healthy critisism but pls do write the reason of your markdown in comment so that i can improve

Comment: Please try the same code but remove the **abs()** function used in **atan2()** may this will solve your problem

Comment: I was trying to make arrow on chess board for my chess engine...the angle require adjustments in few cases,since the no of angles in chess board is limited i hardcoded the adjustments it worked